# How do I stop pygame pictures overlapping

Tags: python, pygame

```
#in the game loop
if event.key == pygame.K_p:
    paused = True
    pause_menu(paused, sound_state)

    if updated_sound_state:
        sound_state = True
        mixer.music.unpause()
    elif not updated_sound_state:
        sound_state = False
        mixer.music.pause()

#the pause menu
def pause_menu(paused, sound_state):
    global updated_sound_state
    updated_sound_state = sound_state

    mixer.music.pause()

    if updated_sound_state:
        screen.blit(sound_on_image, (5, (display_height - sound_image_y_size)))
    if not updated_sound_state:
        screen.blit(sound_off_image, (5, (display_height - sound_image_y_size)))

    while paused:
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    paused = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    if sound_state:
                        updated_sound_state = False
                        paused = False
                        pause_menu(paused=True, sound_state=updated_sound_state)
                    elif not sound_state:
                        updated_sound_state = True
                        paused = False
                        pause_menu(paused=True, sound_state=updated_sound_state)

    return sound_state
```

When I open the pause menu it shows the correct image but when i change sound on or off then it shows both images.

When i back out of pause and go back in to pause it does show the correct image.

How do i fix this?

Comment: oh yes, sorry i forgot to accept an awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** call `pause_menu` recursively. You have to clear an draw the scene in every frame. Get a [`copy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy) of the screen before the `

```py
current_screen = screen.copy()
```

`blit` the copy in the pause loop and draw the menu over it:

```py
screen.blit(current_screen, (0, 0))     
if updated_sound_state:
    screen.blit(sound_on_image, (5, (display_height - sound_image_y_size)))
if not updated_sound_state:
    screen.blit(sound_off_image, (5, (display_height - sound_image_y_size)))
pygame.display.update()
```

---

Complete `pause_menu` function:

```py
def pause_menu(paused, sound_state):
    global updated_sound_state
    updated_sound_state = sound_state

    mixer.music.pause()

    current_screen = screen.copy()

    while paused:
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    paused = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    if sound_state:
                        updated_sound_state = False
                        paused = False
                    elif not sound_state:
                        updated_sound_state = True
                        paused = False
                    
        screen.blit(current_screen, (0, 0))     
        if updated_sound_state:
            screen.blit(sound_on_image, (5, (display_height - sound_image_y_size)))
        if not updated_sound_state:
            screen.blit(sound_off_image, (5, (display_height - sound_image_y_size)))
        pygame.display.update()

    return sound_state
```

---

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage